# Laravel get some values of checkbox

Tags: php, laravel, checkbox

When i use get some values from checkbox by html:

```
<input type="checkbox" name="svdk_doiTuong[]" value="Mocoi"> Sinh viên mồ côi cả cha và mẹ<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="svdk_doiTuong[]" value="Ngheo"> Sinh viên thuộc gia đình hộ nghèo (có sổ hộ nghèo)<br/>
<input type="checkbox" name="svdk_doiTuong[]" value="XuatSac"> Sinh viên có thành tích học tập xuất sắc học kỳ vừa rồi hoặc tân sinh viên là thủ khoa chuyên ngành.<br/>
```

And Laravel 5.x.x i use Request object:

```
public function MyMethod(Request $request)
{
    $cameraVideo = $request->input('svdk_doiTuong');
    ...
}
```

Then, it happens errors, That's "Array to string conversion".
Give me any ideas get some values, thank you.

Comment: $request->get('svdk_doiTuong');

Comment: in which line the error comes

Comment: `$request->input('svdk_doiTuong');` will return an array of checked values, so handle that as an array

Comment: Looks like you are managing the requested input as string, you need to know it's an Array. Probably you are printing it with `echo`, use `dd()` instead.

Comment: @ab_ab : i've tried. it have still rerror like that.

Comment: post your full Mymethod() function

Comment: from my testing the `$request->input('svdk_doiTuong');` or `$request->get('svdk_doiTuong');` or `$request->svdk_doiTuong;` doesn't have any differences. Like @Troyer said "the problem is you are managing the retrieved data as String"

Answer (score 1):

Your code is correct, you can use `$request->svdk_doiTuong;` but there's no difference between `$request->input('svdk_doiTuong')`.

The problem is you are managing the retrieved data as String, when its an Array, probably you are trying to print it doing an `echo` to the variable, you should use the Laravel helper `dd()` or [`var_dump()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.var-dump.php) instead, and if its an Array will not throw any error.

You need to provide more code to see what's causing the error.

Comment: thank you for your detail explanation. i coudn't solve in Request Objects  because it test before going on to create "  dd()" or " var_dump() " @@.

Comment: @ThanhToàn put a `dd($cameraVideo);` just after the `$cameraVideo = $request->input('svdk_doiTuong');` statement and show us what you get.

Comment: When i choose all 3 checkbox; this shows such as: 
array:3 [▼
  0 => "Mocoi"
  1 => "Ngheo"
  2 => "Xuatsac"
]

Comment: Looks like i get it that i choose . What should i do to finish it?

Comment: @ThanhToàn It means the error not doesn't come from `$cameraVideo = $request->input('svdk_doiTuong');` this line. You should show the rest of the code to see what line causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
public function MyMethod(Request $request)
{
   $cameraVideo = $request->svdk_doiTuong;
   ...
}
```

**OR**

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Input;
public function MyMethod(Request $request)
{
   $cameraVideo = Input::get('svdk_doiTuong');
}
```

Comment: post your full Mymethod() function

Comment: Sorry. look like my laravel doesnt understand "Input " although i used "use Input".....Error is ''Class 'Input' not found''

Comment: is there any other codes in your function @ThanhToàn

Comment: @AddWebSolutionPvtLtd . Looks like your code coudn't solve with this proplem

Comment: @afsalc right! but i don't have any ideas convert from array to strings